how to pass token in local storage (async storage) to the backend during api call
the createApi for my project is as follows:
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000",
});

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ["User"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});

I inject the updateUser endpoint using apiSlice.injectEndpoints().
the update user endpoint is as follows:
updateUser: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ data, token }) => ({
        url: `${USERS_URL}/profile`,
        method: "PUT",
        body: data,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }),
    }),

Now, in the backend I generate a token when user registers or logins. when the user (say logs in) the response consists of a user credentials and token. the code for login is:
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) { // matchPw is a method in user model
    const token = generateToken(user._id);
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      token,
    });
  } else {}});

after successful login, the action is dispatched with the response of login which is saved in async storage as:
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCredentials: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo = action.payload;
      AsyncStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(action.payload))
        .then(() => console.log("User successfully saved"))
        .catch((err) => console.error("Error saving user: ", err));
      console.log(state.userInfo)
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.userInfo = null
      AsyncStorage.removeItem("userInfo")
      console.log(state)
    }
  },
});

now, in my reactnative component (updateUserProfile.jsx), I get the userInfo as:
const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.auth.userInfo);
const token = userInfo.token;
console.log(token)

this successfully logs out the token which was created during login.
now when the fields in updateUserProfile.jsx are edited and submitted for updation as:
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
      alert("Passwords donot match");
    } else {
      try {
        console.log("Frontend token: ", token);
        const res = await updateUser({
          data: {
            _id: userInfo._id,
            name,
            email,
            password,
          },
          token,
        }).unwrap();
        dispatch(setCredentials({ ...res })); // update the credentials as well
        alert("Profile updated");
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err?.data?.message || err.error);
      }
    }
  };

Here the line console.log("Frontend token: ", token); also successfully logs out the token.
Now the endpoint that will be hit is /api/users/profile  . This route is a protected route as it requires user to be authenticated i.e user must have a token inorder to update their profile. The code for the route to be protected are as follows:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import User from "../models/userModel.js";

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers.authorization;
  console.log("token: ", token);

  if (token && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    token = token.split(" ")[1];
    //if there is a token, we need to verify it
    try {
      //decode the token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET); //decoded is a object, that now has a userId field
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.userId).select("-password"); //find the user with the id in the decoded object, as we don't want to return the password we do -password
      // doing req.user allows us to access the current user in the protected routes by simply using req.user
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Not authorized, invalid token!");
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized, no token!");
  }
});

export { protect };

in the line console.log("token: ", token); the log that I receive is token: Bearer undefined i.e the query where I passed headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } the "Bearer" has been detected however "token" remain undefined.

Query function accepts only a single arg.

export type query = <QueryArg>(
  arg: QueryArg,
) => string | Record<string, unknown>


Update your updateUser endpoint to consume a single arg object with the properties you need to make the query.
updateUser: builder.mutation({
  query: ({ data, token }) => ({
    url: `${USERS_URL}/profile`,
    method: "PUT",
    body: data,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  }),
}),

Update the dispatched trigger function to pass a single argument. Be sure to also actually unwrap the resolved query result.
try {
  const res = await updateUser({
    data: {
      _id: userInfo._id,
      name,
      email,
      password,
    },
    token
  }).unwrap();
  dispatch(setCredentials({ ...res }));
} catch(error) {
  // handle/ignore errors
}


still the token is undefined, and am receiving the invalid token message. the overall code for the token verification is as follows:
**const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
let token = req.headers.authorization;
console.log("token: ", token);
if (token && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
token = token.split(" ")[1];
try {
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
req.user = await User.findById(decoded.userId).select("-password");
next();
} catch (error) {}
} else {}
})**

@ParikshitAdhikari Are you passing the "Authorization" header anywhere else in your code, like in a custom fetchBaseQuery function in createApi? Do you see the correct "Authorization: Bearer tokenValue" go out on the request to the backend? Where exactly are you seeing the undefined token? Please edit your post with any clarifying details and a more complete [mcve] if necessary.

about passing "Authorization" header, i havent passed it anywhere else in the code. also regarding the Authorization: Bearer tokenValue , just before API call the tokenValue successfully logs out (as I have mentioned in the code above) , but after I receive it in the backend for verification, it logs out to be undefined. I have also updated the post , providing much details about the code

@ParikshitAdhikari Ok, so all the way up to console.log("Frontend token: ", token); in handleSubmit you have the correct expected token value and trigger the updateUser endpoint and pass the token in the query argument. Between here and the backend where is the token value dropped? Do you see token in the query endpoint callback? Do you see the correct token in the authorization header in the request? Is there any additional logic before the /api/users/profile endpoint that you could check the request?

Hey Drew, thanks for helping out. The problem has been solved. Don't know what happened, but it was probably solved due to your first comment. In the night, after those changes, restarted server, client , but it didn't work. However, just woke up and checked  again, and it started working lol.

@ParikshitAdhikari You could roll back to your original code and test if the issue reproduces, and if so, reapply the suggested solution to verify it resolves it.

verified if by rolling back. tysm
